# put color in Listview dymically

Tags: android, listview

I have show Array in listview. with black text color.

if i using android.R.color.black it will give runtime error.

this is my code.

```
list1 =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.scoreView1);
        list2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.scoreView2);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        datalist1.add("Qustion "+ i + "   Correct");
    }
    for (int i = 4; i <= 6; i++) {
        datalist2.add("Qusetion "+ i + "  Correct");
    }



    list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.color.TextColor,datalist1));
    list2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,datalist2));
```

my XML:

```
<resources>

<color name="Background">#E2E2E2</color>
<color name="TextColor">#040404</color>
<color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="Black">#000000</color>
<color name="Red">#FF0000</color>
<color name="Green">#4AA02C</color>

</resources>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where do you exactly are you using R.color.black. And how do you want to change it ?

Comment: i have a color.xml in my project in that some color i had puted. i just use to show black color in listview.

Comment: Are you suing it in xml. Show the xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapterthis,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.color.TextColor,datalist1));

You are using this [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29) for the array adapter. The third argument is

> textViewResourceId    The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated

and you are giving TextColor. You should provide layout id.

Comment: list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.Id.text1,datalist1)); if i write this then it wil properly display with white text color.

Comment: Yes you have to specify the TextColor in the xml file. 1 You have to use your layout not to use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 but to use your own file in which you'll specify TextView's TextColor

Comment: meance i just remove ndroid.R.layout.simple_list_item_1?

Comment: it gives fatal error:   06-23 14:27:56.077: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1218): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040001 type #0x1d is not valid

Answer (score 0):

I had been pursuing the same problem for some time.  Instead of using custom adapter I persisted with using Android.Resource.Layout.TwoLineListItem for my view adapter.  My hack way of achieving text color changes dynamically is by declaring a dummy textview in the GetView method of the ListViewAdapter.

code example here:

```
TextView tmptxt = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Android.Resource.Id.Text2);
tmptxt.Text = glt.Genre; // my source for the displayed text in the second line of the listview item.
tmptxt.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);
glt.Genre = tmptxt.Text;
view.FindViewById<TextView> (Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = glt.Title;
view.FindViewById<TextView> (Android.Resource.Id.Text2).Text = (glt.Genre);  // now displayed with lightgreen text color
return view;
```